Issue with "OK" button not closing alert in Swift
I have an alert in Swift that is supposed to close when the "OK" button is clicked. Unfortunately, this doesn't happen. Visually, I can see in the app that the "OK" button is clickable once, but nothing happens afterward. Additionally, the "OK" button becomes unclickable, and the debug message "OK clicked" is never displayed.
import SwiftUI

struct MobileDeviceDetailView: View {
  @ObservedObject var api: JamfAPI
  var deviceId: String
  var deviceName: String

  @State private var showAlert = false
  @State private var showConfirmationDialog = false
  @State private var alertMessage = ""
  @State private var alertTitle = "Info"

  var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
      Form {
        Section(
          header: Text("Action"),
          content: {
            Button(action: {
              // Update Inventory
              api.sendCommandDevice(
                deviceId: deviceId,
                command: "UpdateInventory"
              ) { success, message in
                self.alertMessage = message
                self.alertTitle = success ? "Done" : "Error"
                self.showAlert = true
              }
            }) {
              Text("Update Inventory")
                .padding()
                .cornerRadius(10)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .overlay(
              RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 2)
                .padding(5)
            )
          })
      }
    }
    .alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
      Alert(
        title: Text(alertTitle),
        message: Text(alertMessage),
        dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")) {
          print("OK clicked")
          self.showAlert = false  // Zustand zurücksetzen
        }
      )
    }
  }
}

Here the important API part
if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
  print(httpResponse.statusCode)
  if httpResponse.statusCode == 201 {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      completion(true, "\(command) wurde durchgeführt")
    }
  } else {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      completion(false, "Fehler, versuch es später erneut")
    }
  }
}

I see in the debug logs the status 201.

I cannot reproduce the behavior. I suspect it's related to the API call and a thread issue. Consider to use async/await rather than a completion handler. And delete the line to reset showAlert. The framework does it on your behalf.

@vadian thanks, I removed the line in my code for the reset. I added the part from the API. Do you have a hint, what I must change here?

I would change sendCommandDevice to adopt async/await and put the button action into a method inside the MobileDeviceDetailView struct. This avoids the DispatchQueue calls. By the way nowadays Task { @MainActor in should be preferred over Grand Central Dispatch.

Cannot reproduce your problem either.
All works well for me without the api.sendCommandDevice.
You have showConfirmationDialog, do you have other code/dialog, eg confirmationDialog
that you are not showing?
